# Impresspages 4 Model.php

Tags: php, model, impresspages

I have Model.php:

```
<?php
/**
* @package   ImpressPages
*/

namespace Plugin\My_plugin_name;

class Model
{
public static function getVideoList()
{
    $videos = ipDb()->selectAll('plugin_db', '*', array('language'=> ipContent()->getCurrentLanguage()->getCode()), 'ORDER BY row_number ASC');
    return $videos;
}

}
```

But when I try to call to this function in Widget/some_plugin/skin/view.php

```
$videos = Model::getVideoList();
```

I get:

Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in .......Widget/some_plugin/skin/view.php

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I've already answered this question. You have to use full namespace:

```
$videos = \Plugin\MyPlugin\Model::getVideoList();
```